# Should Object using @Mock annotation be set detailed value?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I am new to Mockito and I have a question. Let's say I try to have an object instance in my testing method. I know I can use `@Mock` to have it and that's because we try to isolate the testing from that Object methods. However, to control the testing branch, I do need to set some values in this object. Should I still use `Mock` or I should simply use new `Object()` way to instantiate it? Or does it not matter (each way is fine)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's find out, shall we?!

```
import org.mockito.Mockito;

class Scratch {  
    public final static String STATIC_CONST = "static const";
    private final String JUST_CONST = "private const";
    protected String protectedField = "protected field";
    String packageProtectedField = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scratch mocked = Mockito.mock(Scratch.class);
        System.out.println("static    = " + mocked.STATIC_CONST);
        System.out.println("const     = " + mocked.JUST_CONST);
        System.out.println("protected = " + mocked.protectedField);
        System.out.println("package   = " + mocked.packageProtectedField);

        mocked.packageProtectedField = "but now";
        System.out.println("updated  = " + mocked.packageProtectedField);
    }
}
```

The above prints:

> static    = static const
>
> const     = private const
>
> protected = null
>
> package   = null
>
> updated   = but now

Some thoughts:

Obviously, the `static const` is really what you would expect (I used `mocked.STATIC_CONST` to get the value, but hey, it is static, so the value doesn't come from `mocked` but from the Scratch class definition anyway).

A bit surprising, at least for me is that **assigning** fields of a mocked object actually works. But please note: assignments in the original class are only effective for that `final` field. In other words: Mockito gets that one right, but not for non-final fields.

Even more surprisingly, one can store values into the mock...

But honestly, nothing of that really matters. You see, in a sound design, all your mutable fields should be **private** in the very first place. That mutable state represents the absolute core of your objects. **No** outside code should ever deal with those! In other words: ideally, even your tests do not care about the internal state of your objects (in very rare situations, it might make sense to have a package protected getter method to access internal state for ease of verification, but that should be a rare exception).

Beyond that: when you mock an object, you **absolutely** should not be dealing in any ways with **fields** of that mock. You see: all the *methods* on that mock ... they have nothing to do with the original source code in your class. They are just that: empty shells that you can configure/verify using the corresponding Mockito methods. Let that sink in: the actual content of fields in a mocked object can't matter: because the methods that would normally deal with these fields ... "are not there"!

So, long story short: as shown, mocked objects can carry state. But as explained: you should ignore that aspect completely. The only correct way to use mocks is by specifying/verifying method calls on them.

Finally: I would expect that EasyMock, PowerMock(ito) behave in similar ways. On the other hand, I wouldn't be surprised either when other mocking frameworks actually behave slightly different. I only tested with Mockito because, imho, in 2018, Mockito is the one and only mocking framework one should be using when writing unit tests for the JVM.

Comment: Such detailed explanation!! Thanks!!